# Why does Swift Treat a Mixed Type Array as a Single Type Array Sometimes?

Tags: arrays, swift, types

I've recently started learning Swift and have a little confusion around the way types in arrays are treated.

From my understanding an array can have different types within it. For example:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3.0, 4, "myString"]
```

When I write this in the XCode Playground and do a println() I get the expected output:

```
[1, 2, 3.0, 4, "String"]
```

When I remove the String in the array I get the following output:

```
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

Why is Swift treating the integers as doubles? This caused me some confusion when I ran the following code in the Playground:

```
import UIKit

var arr = [2.0, 3, 4, 5]

for (index, value) in enumerate(arr) {
    arr[index] = value / 2
}
```

and I expected the following output:

```
[1.0, 1, 2, 2]
```

but the output was:

```
[1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5]
```

Why does Swift automatically change the types of the ints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From my understanding an array can have different types within it.

That understanding is incorrect, arrays can only contain one specific type.

In fact, if you type your original example into a playground that contains *nothing else* (that is, delete the “import UIKit” or “import Cocoa” statement), it will fail to compile.

The `Array` struct in the Swift standard library looks like this:

```
struct Array<T> : MutableCollectionType, Sliceable {
    // methods and properties
}
```

That `T` is a “generic placeholder”.  When you declare an array, it is replaced with the type the array contains.  But `T` can only be of one type.

When you declare a variable without specifying the type, Swift will attempt to “infer” the type.  That is, it will figure out all the possible types it could be from the context and pick one based on a (fairly extensive) bunch of rules.

`Double` and `Int` both conform to `IntegerLiteralConvertible` protocol.  This means you can create either from a literal such as `1`.  However, `Int` is the default.  If you want a `Double` you need to be explicit.

```
// i will be an Int, the default
let i = 1
// j will also be an Int
let j: Int = 1
// k will be a Double
let k: Double = 1
```

`Double` also conforms to `FloatLiteralConvertible`, but `Int` doesn’t:

```
// f will be a Double, the default:
let f = 1.0
// or you can declare a Float:
let g: Float = 1.0
// but this won’t work:
let h: Int = 1.0 // compiler error
```

When you declare an array, similarly Swift will try and figure out what the `T` type the array contains.  It lists out all the possibilities and picks one.  In the case of `[1.0, 1, 2]`, the possibility of it containing an `Int` is ruled out by the `1.0` value, so `T == Double` is picked.

Similarly, when you declare `[1, 2, 3.0, 4, "String"]`, `Double` is also ruled out.  The only type that would work is something that adheres to `IntegerLiteralConvertible`, `FloatLiteralConvertible` and `StringLiteralConvertible`.  *Nothing* in the standard Swift library of types does that.

So why does your original example work?  When you import UIKit, it pulls in a type, `NSObject` that does do exactly that.  So Swift picks it.